# How can I change the timezone on a read only operating system protected by overlayroot?

Tags: read-only, chroot, timezone, overlayfs

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 installation mounted using overlayroot as a read only partition.

I also have a read write partition on the same drive.

I need to be able to change the timezone setting of the PC but without disabling overlayroot. I can see that the timezone is saved in the file `/etc/timezone` but obviously any changes made with overlayroot active will be lost after reboot.

I tried disabling overlayroot and then deleting the `/etc/timezone` file and replacing it with a symbolic link with the same name to a timezone file on my Read/Write partition. I thought that any changes to the `/etc/timezone` file by the operating system might them be saved in the timezone file on my read/write drive. However on testing I see that the GUI time/date setting utility is actually overwriting the symbolic link, and also the RTC seems to get reset to 12:00am.

---

I've spent a few hours on this and come to understand that the `overlayroot-chroot` command will allow me to make changes to the underlying read only operating system. I tried using the following ...

```
sudo overlayroot-chroot
timedatectl set-timezone "Europe/Paris"
exit
```

This all appears to work at first but after rebooting the time has reset back to the original setting - "Australia/Sydney". After some testing I can see that even after using the 'sudo overlayroot-chroot' command, the `timedatectl` command is still writing to the overlay filesystem and all changes are lost after rebooting.

I know the chroot is working because I can make permanent changes to files in the `/etc/` directory.

Why is `timedatectl` not able to write into the chroot?